# PHP remove numbers from strings not containing @ and #

Tags: php, regex

I tried using `preg_replace` but it didn't correctly work as those variables containing @ and # also had their numbers removed...

eg. @cv12--> @cv12 and cv12-->cv

Comment: Where's the code you're using?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$stringCheck = strpos($stringToSearch , $searchPattern );` the $searchPattern would equal @ and then use `if($stringCheck == false) removeNumbers($stringToSearch);` simple as that.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question quality is poor:

```
$s = '@vc12'; // or whatever...

// verify # and @ don't exist
if (strpos($s,'@') === false && strpos($s,'#') === false)
{
  // replace all numbers and store result back to variable
  $s = preg_replace('/\d/','',$s);
}
```

[example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f6386b80f1a44b09c0b03b2aed2a3029912cadf)

References:

- [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (returns `false` when `$needle` isn't found)
- [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)